# Botframework V4: How to send video attachment?

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm sorry if this look like an effortless question but i really can't find it anywhere. There is no sample in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) too. And there is not much guide on botframework v4 on internet. Can someone give me an example of a video card or video hero card, or Video hero card in carousel form? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hihi!

The Bot Framework samples repo has a sample in their C# section called ["06. Using Cards"](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/06.using-cards). If you run this sample, it will show an example of all the cards that the bot framework can do, channel permitting. In the sample, you can select 'Show all' to see the cards in a carousel, and one of the cards is a video card.

```
private static VideoCard GetVideoCard()
    {
        var videoCard = new VideoCard
        {
            Title = "Big Buck Bunny",
            Subtitle = "by the Blender Institute",
            Text = "Big Buck Bunny (code-named Peach) is a short computer-animated comedy film by the Blender Institute," +
                   " part of the Blender Foundation. Like the foundation's previous film Elephants Dream," +
                   " the film was made using Blender, a free software application for animation made by the same foundation." +
                   " It was released as an open-source film under Creative Commons License Attribution 3.0.",
            Image = new ThumbnailUrl
            {
                Url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg/220px-Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg",
            },
            Media = new List<MediaUrl>
            {
                new MediaUrl()
                {
                    Url = "http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4",
                },
            },
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>
            {
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = "Learn More",
                    Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                    Value = "https://peach.blender.org/",
                },
            },
        };

        return videoCard;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what i need.